# How to adjust xticks labels while plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, xticks

As in the image below, the rotated xticks are ticked in the middle of the label.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE3ew.png
Instead, I want it ticked in the end so that there is no overlap.
the code to get this is

```
sns.heatmap(cov,annot=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [this link](https://www.drawingfromdata.com/how-to-rotate-axis-labels-in-seaborn-and-matplotlib) answer your question?

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45, 
           horizontalalignment='right',
           fontweight='light'  
           )
```